# How to build mongo aggregation pipeline with nested and/or conditions?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to build an aggregation pipeline that that filters out documents using a `AND(OR(AND)` condition.

What I need is something like

`if (A == "A" && B == "B" && (C == NULL || (C != NULL && C == "C")))`

My query looks like below.

The inner part:

```
var x = new BsonDocument
                {
                    {
                        "$or",
                        new BsonArray
                        {
                            new BsonDocument {{"C", BsonNull.Value}},
                            new BsonDocument
                            {
                                {
                                    "$and",
                                    new BsonArray
                                    {
                                        new BsonDocument
                                        {
                                            {
                                                "C",
                                                new BsonDocument {{"$ne", BsonNull.Value}}
                                            }
                                        },
                                        new BsonDocument {{"C", C}}
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };
```

Then the full filter is

```
var filter = new BsonDocument
            {
                {
                    "$and",
                    new BsonArray
                    {
                        new BsonDocument {{"A", A}},
                        new BsonDocument {{"B", B}},
                        x
                    }
                }
            };
```

Then I call this like:

```
var y = await collection.Aggregate().Match(filter).ToListAsync();
```

However, it not returning any results though it should.

In my debugger, final Bson looks like:

```
{
    {
        "$and": [
            {
                "A": "A"
            },
            {
                "B": "B"
            },
            {
                "$or": [
                    {
                        "C": null
                    },
                    {
                        "$and": [
                            {
                                "C": {
                                    "$ne": null
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "C": "C"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Use mongo shell to figure out the right query using MQL, then translate to C#.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to figure it out. I changed the query to build it as a match as well since it's easier to test with mongo shell:

```
var match = new BsonDocument
{
    {
        "$match",
        new BsonDocument
        {
            {
                "$and",
                new BsonArray
                {
                    new BsonDocument {{"A", A}},
                    new BsonDocument {{"B", B}},
                    new BsonDocument
                    {
                        {
                            "$or",
                            new BsonArray
                            {
                                new BsonDocument {{C, BsonNull.Value}},
                                new BsonDocument
                                {
                                    {
                                        "$and",
                                        new BsonArray
                                        {
                                            new BsonDocument
                                            {
                                                {
                                                    "C",
                                                    new BsonDocument {{"$ne", BsonNull.Value}}
                                                }
                                            },
                                            new BsonDocument {{"C", C}}
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Hope this helps anyone running into a problem with similar query.

Comment: in case you're unaware, you can do `collection.Aggregate().Match("{ json_string }").ToListAsync()`. there's no need to muddy up your c# code with all those `new BsonDocument` bits.